# if a video contains one short scene and repeats N times for 6 hours, is there a video compression algorithm that will detect the looping scene?

Tags: video-compression

- for example

  - there are lots of videos that contain a single short scene that is about 20 seconds long
  - then loops the scene for about 6 hours
  - the video then has music
  - the purpose of the video is mostly the music

##### if a video contains one short scene and repeats N times for 6 hours, is there a video compression algorithm that will detect the looping scene?

- then only compress and store the short scene once
- then somehow re-use the same data each time the scene is repeated

(i guess this would require some sort of algorithm to detect looping scenes and detect where the looping starts repeating itself. then a modified video-compression spec to allow you to re-use the compressed data for one scene for a later scene at a different time. )

Comment: This is how compression works in general - remove redundant information, so I suspect that any good compression algorithm will do this naturally. If no-one has a specific answer it would be a good test in case there is a limit in the span of the video over which redundancy is no longer considered. You can simply concatenate N short segments and compare file size to a equally long but non-repeating video of similar quality--- and if it is close to 1/Nth in size increase the length of each segment to see if the effectiveness is sensitive to length.